# Создание анимации загрузки для нескольких фотографий

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

У меня есть загрузочная область, в которою я кидаю фотографии. После чего вызывается функция **saveFiles(formData,resolve)**, в которой для фотографии создается объект с  анимацией загрузки.

Проблема в том, что эта функция не работает нормально для нескольких загрузчиков. Анимация доходит до конца только в последнем загрузчике. Это происходит из-за того что при новом вызове **saveFiles(formData,resolve)** объект загрузчика перезаписывается.

Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке нескольких файлов функция **saveFiles(formData,resolve)** вызывалась для каждого объекта отдельно?

```
 function saveFiles(formData, resolve){        
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('POST', 'index.php?type=putPicture');
     var load = new Loader(); //Create object of loader
     load.init(120, 120, "loader" + counter, 50, ".loading" + (count - 1));
     counter++;
     xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
         load.goProgress(event.loaded, event.total);
     }
     xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){         
         if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
         {
             var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
             resolve(response)            
         }
     }    
     xhr.send(formData);
     ajaxRequests.push(xhr);        
}
```

Прототип функции `goProgress`

```
Loader.prototype.goProgress = function (cur, tot) {
    var obj = this;
    d3.transition().tween("progress", function () {
        var i = d3.interpolate(obj.progress, cur / tot);
        return function (t) {
            obj.progress = i(t);
            $("." + obj.block + " g g .foreground").attr("d", obj.arc.endAngle(obj.twoPi * obj.progress));
            $("." + obj.block + " g g text").text(obj.formatPercent(obj.progress));
        };
    });
```

Comment: Объект загрузчика это `load`? Если да, то приведи его код.

Comment: Да вот пример кода.
`Loader.prototype.goProgress = function(cur, tot){ 
var obj = this; 
d3.transition().tween("progress", function() { 
var i = d3.interpolate(obj.progress, cur / tot); 
return function(t) { 
obj.progress = i(t); 
$("." + obj.block + " g g .foreground").attr("d", obj.arc.endAngle(obj.twoPi * obj.progress)); 
$("." + obj.block + " g g text").text(obj.formatPercent(obj.progress)); 
}; 
}); 
}`

Comment: что за объект `d3`?

Comment: Стандартный объект библиотеки  d3.js.

Comment: А если load превратить в массив/JSON и объекты хранить там? Либо сохранять туда какой-нибудь айдишник объекта и в дальнейшем, если надо обратиться к ранее созданному объекту, то просто обращаться по айдишнику?

Comment: Создавал, не получается. Так как не возможно с функции
xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
         load.goProgress(event.loaded, event.total);
}
обратиться к глобальному массиву с объектами лоадера

Answer (score 1):

Храните все загружаемые файлы в объекте (точнее информацию о них), после того как этот файл (картинка) загрузилась, находите по ключу и удаляйте из объекта эту запись, после того как объект стал пустым, можете смело удалять троббер (анимацию загрузки). Если она у Вас идет на весь экран, еже ли она для каждого фала отдельно, то в объекте храните и сам троббер для каждой картинки, удаляя по ключу запись в объекте удаляете нужный троббер.

Ничего сложного и фантастического, объекты Вам в помощь! :)

Второй вариант я делал так когда мне нужно было контролировать загрузку каждого фала отдельно и рисовать для него полосу загрузки для каждого свою:

```
var handleFileSelect = function(e){
    var eventData = e.dataTransfer || e.target;
    var $tbody = $(selectors.table).find('.tbody');
    var files = eventData.files; // FileList object.
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
        uploadFile(file, $tbody);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
};

var uploadFiles = [];

var uploadFile = function(file, $tbody) {
    var $cloneFile = $icClone.clone();
    var $percent = $('<div/>', {class: 'percent'});
    var $progressBar = $('<div/>',{class: 'progress-bar'}).html($percent);
    var $percentText = $cloneFile.find('.ic-date');
    var xhr;
    var formData = new FormData();
    uploadFiles.push(file);
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('dir', ic.openDir);

    $percentText.html('0%');
    $percent.css({width: '0%', opacity: 0});

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        ic.uploadFiles = $.grep(ic.uploadFiles, function(value){
            return value !== file;
        });
        getFiles();
        $percentText.html('100%');
        $percent.css({width: '100%', opacity: 1});
    }, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
            if (percentLoaded < 100) {
                $percentText.html(percentLoaded + '%');
                $percent.css({width: percentLoaded + '%', opacity: (percentLoaded/100)});
            }
        } else {
            // No data to calculate on
        }
    }, false);

    $cloneFile.prepend($progressBar);
    $cloneFile.attr('data-name', file.name).removeClass(classNames.icMenu);
    $cloneFile.find('.ic-checkbox').addClass(classNames.hide);
    $cloneFile.find('.ic-name i.fa').addClass(classNames.faFileTextO);
    $cloneFile.find('.ic-text').append(file.name);
    $cloneFile.find('.ic-delete').removeClass(classNames.icDelete).addClass(classNames.icBreakUploadItem).on('click', function(){
        xhr.abort();
        $cloneFile.remove();
    });
    $cloneFile.find('.ic-size').append(file.size + ' B');
    $tbody.prepend($cloneFile);
    xhr.open("post", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(formData);
};
```